# C++ SDL_ttf cannot find freetype262.dll

Tags: c++, winapi, c++14, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

i am trying to make a project in SDL2 C++ and use `SDL_ttf.h`, to draw text, but when i run it (i am only using `TTF_Init()` here, nothing else) i get the error "could not find "freetype262.dll" reinstalling the program may fix this issue".

i tried installing freetype, nothing happened.

Comment: The DLL needs to be on the operating system's search path. See the Microsoft documentation on the LoadLibrary() function for an explanation of how the Windows OS searches for DLLs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which dlls do you have next to the exe? Is FreeType among them?